# Отношения один-ко-многим и многие-ко-многим в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Как правильно делать связку `users` и `post` в MySQL? В таблице `users` есть пользователь, который добавляет публикации (это будет таблица `post`). Как будет правильнее связать: один к одному или один ко многим?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пользователь может создавать несколько постов, то отношение должно быть **Один-Ко-Многим**. Если же пользователь в системе может создать только один пост, то отношение будет **Один-К-Одному**.

**UPD.** Пример.
Пусть будут два вида пользователей:

- Авторы - могут создавать посты;
- Редакторы - могут дополнять и редактировать посты (чем то похоже на ru.SO).

Таким образом получается следующие отношения: Один-Ко-Многим между автором и постами и Многие-Ко-Многим между редакторами и постами. Таблицы будут следующие:

```
    users
id | name
---+------
1  | Vasya
2  | Petya
3  | Vanya

    post
id | title | autor_id | text
---+-------+----------+---------------
1  | PHP   | 1        | Blah-blah-blah

    post_editor
user_id | post_id
--------+---------
2       | 1
3       | 1
```

Таким образом можем увидеть, что пост `PHP` создал `Vasya`, а редактировали `Petya` и `Vanya` (отношение Многие-Ко-Многим реализуется через второстепенную таблицу, в нашем случае через таблицу `post_editor`).

Comment: А если каждый зарегистрированный пользователь может добавить неограниченное количество новостей, то это многие ко многим?

Comment: @Ilnyr все равно отношение один-ко-многим. Отношение многие-ко-многим имеет место быть, если бы несколько пользователей могли публиковать одну запись.

Comment: @Ilnyr пример отношения многие-ко-многим: когда несколько писателей пишут одну книгу. Причем дальше они могут писать другие книги с другими писателями.

Comment: Например, несколько администраторов могут изменять, дополнить одну статью, т.к. у них есть полномочия, а у обычных пользователей нет таких полномочий. Значит у админов в этом случае многие ко многим, а у обычных юзеров один ко многим. Правильно понял?

Comment: @Ilnyr в случае с админами с правами на всё явного отношения нет вообще :)

Comment: @Ilnyr обновил ответ, все объяснил.

Answer (score 0):

один ко многим, в таблице юзеров первичный ключ id например а в таблице пост вторичный ключ подвязать

Comment: **Внешний** ключ :) Приведите пример DDL по созданию таких таблиц и ключа, а то в нынешнем виде ответ к плюсам ну вообще не располагает.